# JavaScript While Loop | Guessing Game

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to create a "guessing game" using javascript. I'm new to JavaScript and can't seem to get it to work.

```
var theNumber = Math.round(50*Math.random());

function pickNumber () 
{
    theNumber = Math.round(50*Math.random());
}

function compare ()
{
    var choice = 0;
    // Write a three-way conditional that compares choice to
    // theNumber and displays the correct message.
}
```

The compare function is supposed to be the only thing I need to edit. Below I've added the HTML form that I'm trying to manipulate.

```
<form name="controls">

  <select name="guess" onchange="compare();">
    <option value=0> 0 </option>
    <option value=1> 1 </option>
    <option value=2> 2 </option>
    <option value=3> 3 </option>
    <option value=4> 4 </option>
    <option value=5> 5 </option>
    <option value=6> 6 </option>
    <option value=7> 7 </option>
    <option value=8> 8 </option>
    <option value=9> 9 </option>
    <option value=10> 10 </option>

  </select>

  <p>
    <input type=text size=50 name="response">
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type=button
      value="Pick New Number"
      onclick="pickNumber();">
  </p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function compare(choice){
if (choice===theNumber){return "Win"}
else if(choice >= theNumber){return "Lower")
else {return "Higher"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
var theNumber = Math.round(50*Math.random());


  function pickNumber () 
 {
   theNumber = Math.round(50*Math.random());

 }


function compare ()
 {
    var val = document.getElementById('sel').value;
    if(val === theNumber) {
      document.getElementById('response').value = "Chosen Number is correct";
    }
   else if(val < theNumber){
     {
      document.getElementById('response').value = "Chosen Number is smaller";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('response').value = "Chosen Number is greater";
    }

 }
```

**HTML**

```
  <form>
    <select id = "sel"name="guess" onchange="compare()">
      <option value=0> 0 </option>
      <option value=1> 1 </option>
      <option value=2> 2 </option>
      <option value=3> 3 </option>
      <option value=4> 4 </option>
      <option value=5> 5 </option>
      <option value=6> 6 </option>
      <option value=7> 7 </option>
      <option value=8> 8 </option>
      <option value=9> 9 </option>
      <option value=10> 10 </option>

     </select>

     <p>
     <input id = "response" type=text size=50 name="response">
     </p>

     <p>
       <input type=button
          value="Pick New Number"
           onclick="pickNumber()">
     </p>

     </form>
```